# Visual Studio 2015 syntax highlighting for CSS does not work inside of vbhtml razor pages

Tags: css, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015, styles

I have vbhtml pages to edit and everything syntax-highlights fine (c#, javascript, html), except for css enclosed in the `<style>...</style>` block.  It even does proper syntax highlighting of inline css (e.g. `<td style="color:yellow"...`).

Is there a trick to get VS2015 to highlight css inside of `<style>...</style>` block that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my own question.  If you have any kind of Razor syntax inside your `<style>...</style>`, the syntax highlighting stops.  For instance:

```
<style>
    .foo{
        background-image:url(@Url.Content("~/")Content/Images/shell/home_16.jpg);
    }
</style>
```

The solution is to separate classes with Razor into a separate `<style>...</style>` block.